# makefile concepts

Tags: gcc, makefile, cygwin, gnu-make

can anyoone help me.
this is the code for make file 
i'm just trying to save different objective files at different directories is that possible?
in the below code.

```
OBJECTS = objj/mall.o objj/fall.o 

BACK = kajj/ball.o kajj/call.o

DIR = objj kajj rajj 

execc/gola : $(OBJECTS) $(BACK)
    gcc $^  -o  $@
$(OBJECTS):objj/%.o:%.c
    mkdir   $(DIR)
    gcc -c  $<  -o  $@
$(BACK) : kajj/%.o
```

i want to save the mall.o fall.o in objj and ball.o and call.o in kajj i'm stucked up here i dont know how to cotinue further can anyone help me if we use %.o:%.c it replaces all obj files one on one but how to seperate them. and anyone please tell me what these line really does $(OBJECTS):objj/%.o:%.c.im unable to understand we can have only one colon in our line but here we have two im confused help me out guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the two column rules, consider what is before the first as the actual targets, and what is after the first column as a pattern rule.

Thus, to compile the objects in kajj, you could replace your last rule by:

```
$(BACK): kajj/%.o: %.c
    mkdir   $(DIR)
    gcc -c  $<  -o  $@
```